# Missing method setCardBackgroundColor

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-cardview

In reference to the class CardView method setCardBackgroundColor is defined, but the Eclipse doesn't see it. How do I get this method was visible?

[image: Missing method setCardBackgroundColor]

Comment: which version of CardView are you using?

Comment: @Blackbelt , How to know the version CardView? I use Support Library version 22.2.

Comment: I am using `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'` and I have it

Comment: @Blackbelt Oh, it turns out, wasn't updated list of classes in Eclipse. I just deleted the folder "bin" of appcompat library and then made new methods :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import correct version of CardView.
If not sure about correct version then update sdk and and import CardView by navigating to sdk\extras\android\support\v7.